# Dynamicaly updating field that references other table?

Tags: oracle

Lets say I have Tables A and B :

```
              A
+---------+-------+----------+--------+
| ID      | NAME  | B_ID     | B_NAME |   
+---------+-------+----------+ -------+
|       1 | Joe   |    1     | Sue    |
+---------+-------+----------+--------+

        B
+---------+-------+
| ID      | NAME  |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | Sue   |
+---------+-------+
```

where A.B_ID references B.ID as foreign key. 
Is there any way to declare that `A.B_NAME := B.NAME` such that A.B_NAME is updated when I update B.NAME or can this only be achieved by a trigger that fires on updates on A ?

Comment: [AskTOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5773459616034) on why this is wrong, but also how to do it, kind of. There is no `on update cascade` option though, which I think is what you were hoping for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The truth is: your data model is wrong, it isn't normalized.

Remove column `B_NAME` from table `A`, it shouldn't exist there.

Maintain the name in table `B`. Whenever you need to reference it, do so by joining `A.B_ID = B.ID`.

Comment: I put the B_Name filed into A because I wanted to make my data easier to read, but after thinking about what you said i realized that the same can be achieved with a view, without saving redundant data in A.